# Convergence in Distribution to the normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

let $ X_1,X_2+,...,$ be independent and identically distributed random variables with Poisson Distribution, does 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{2i-1} - X_{2i})$$

Converge in distribution to the normal distributions as $ n \rightarrow \infty$ ?

**what I have done so far**

So I have calculated the expectation and variance to be $0$ and $2n\lambda$ respectively ( for the parameter $\lambda$). I have no idea where to go from here. I have another question similar in nature but with a general random variable(IID with finite mean and variance) and the sum being  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{2i} - X_{i})$$

What type of things am I looking at here so I can prove these kinds of things?
Is there the Borel-Cantelli lemma's help?

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Have you tried computed the expression of the characteristic function (using the fact that the summands are independent, and [Skellam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution)-distributed) to see if that converges pointwise to the CF of a Gaussian?

Comment: No, I haven't. Can't believe I forgot about characteristic functions. Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, it also looks like a direct application of the Central Limit Theorem (but manipulating characteristic functions is more fun).

Comment: Thank you so much Clement! This helped me out so much! Solved both problems now! I agree chractersitic functions are definitely more fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*An approach based on the characteristic functions:*

We will use the three following results:

- if $X,Y$ are independent $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ random variables, then $Z=X-Y$ follows a [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) and has characteristic function
  $$
  \varphi_Z(t) = \mathbb{E} e^{it Z} = e^{-2\lambda + \lambda\left(e^{it} + e^{-it}\right)};
  $$
- the characteristic function of a $\operatorname{Gaussian}(\mu,\sigma)$ random variable is $\varphi_{\mu,\sigma}(t) = e^{i\mu t - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2}$;
- a sequence $(X_n)_n$ of random variables converges in distribution to a random variable $X$ iff their characteristic functions converge pointwise:
  $$
  \varphi_{X_n}(t) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \varphi_X(t)
  $$
  for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. (This is [Lévy's continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem).)

---

Consider the (sequence of) random variables $Y_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n (X_{2n-1}- X_{2n})$. As the summands $Z_n\stackrel{\rm def}{=}X_{2n-1}- X_{2n}$ are independent and the $X_i$ are i.i.d. and follow a $\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ distribution, we can write, for every fixed $t\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\varphi_{Y_n}(t) = \mathbb{E} e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n Z_n }
= \prod_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E} e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}Z_n }
= \prod_{k=1}^n e^{-2\lambda + \lambda\left(e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}} + e^{-i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)}.
$$

But when $n\to\infty$, we have that
$$
e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}} + e^{-i\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}}
= 2 - \frac{t^2}{n} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
so that
$$
\varphi_{Y_n}(t) 
= \prod_{k=1}^n e^{-\lambda\frac{t^2}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}
= e^{-\sum_{k=1}^n \left( \lambda\frac{t^2}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}
= e^{-\lambda t^2 + o\left(1\right)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^{-\lambda t^2}.$$

Recalling the expression of the characteristic function of a $\operatorname{Gaussian}(\mu,\sigma)$ random variable, we conclude that $(Y_n)_n$ converges in distribution to a $\operatorname{Gaussian}(0,\sqrt{2\lambda})$.